# Eclipse won't create an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the Android SDK and everything went fine. Next, I installed Eclipse Indigo and the ADT plugin. No errors there. But when I go to create a new Android project, I get the error that '\lib\tools\proguard-project.txt' is missing. Before that, I was getting the same error for \lib\tools\proguard.txt'.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you follow Step 4 on http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html ?

Comment: Try to update the SDK and SDK-tools

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that requires me to stay at an older version of the SDK, so i can't just update. I was able to fix this problem by searching for the proguard-project.txt file (which appeared twice in my SDK folder) and copying it into the file path that the error shows.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the SDK , and the ADT . But did you configure the ADT plugin in Eclipse ?
I faced the same problem , fixed it by following the step "Configuring the ADT Plugin" in the installation doc of ADT plugin .

You can find it here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing
Go to the section : "Configuring the ADT Plugin" and check if you did that .

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, this could also be caused by a mismatch of Android SDK and ADT version, make sure you are using the latest versions of both SDK as well as for ADT...